# How to get a Resource in Apache Brooklyn

Tags: java, maven, brooklyn

I am trying to build my own entity, which is based on VanillaWindowsProcess. The idea is, after the installation of the windows Machine, to execute some powershell commands, which are in a file.

I tried something which I used a lot of times in another Java projects to get a resource:

```
private void runInstallationScript() {
    List<String> lines;
    try {
        lines = FileUtils.readLines(
                new File(TalendWindowsProcessWinRmDriver.class.getResource("/my/path/file.txt").getFile()),
                "utf-8");
        executePsScript(lines);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Error reading the file: ", e);
    }
}
```

But I'm always getting the following:

> ava.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'file:/opt/workspace/incubator-brooklyn/usage/dist/target/brooklyn-dist/brooklyn/lib/dropins/myProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/my/path/file.txt' does not exist

It is strange, because the file is in the jar in that path. I did a test (without Apache Brooklyn infrastructure) and it works, but the other way, it does not.

The project follows the Maven standard structure and the file itself is under, src/main/resources/my/path/file.txt

Is there something that is wrong? Or maybe there is another approach to get that file? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a resource inside a jar as a `File` object. You need to use an `InputStream` (or an `URL`) to access it.

Since you are already using `getResource`, you should change the method `FileUtils.readLines` to accept an `InputStream` (or an `URL`) as input.

If you don't have access to the source code, you can write your own method or use [`Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) for Java >= 7.